# Do T-SQL MDF files have possibility to check its data integrity?

Tags: t-sql, ntfs

I have a huge mdf file on my SQL Server and doubt concerning its data integrity. I am performing manipulations with tables in this DB and noticed about many disk bad block reports in my Windows System Event Log (the File System is NTFS). I suspect that this errors may be connected to my operation with this DB. My questing is in the case some part of data in the mdf file is corrupted does SQL Server have possibility to detect this data integrity problem? Is there some error checking mechanism in the mdf: per-record or per-table crc, etc? In the case it is not performed automatically how could I test it manually?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question but.

[DBCC CHECKDB (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx)

[DBCC CHECKTABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174338.aspx)

If you are throwing bad block errors then most likely you have a disk going bad.   You need to fix you hardware problem.

Comment: I understand that it's dangerous and I need to fix the HW problem ASAP. But my question is concerning presence of data protection on SQL sever layer, not file system

Comment: What is dangerous?   Those commands or using a disk with sectors going bad?   Why would Microsoft offer dangerous commands?